How to get the orientation normal vector to align the camera?
Suppose I have a plane oriented in a specific direction. I want to align the camera to match the plane's direction for rendering, and I would like to achieve this using Python.


Find a median normal and tangent, move and rotate the camera according to that normal and tangent, and then use camera_fit_coords for the final adjustment.

It's not a python solution (you've tagged your question as python).
Select the plane (or the face of the plane in Edit mode if the origin of the plane is not aligned with the face), open the Transform Orientations panel and click on the "+" to create a new orientation, keep this new orientation selected:

Select your camera, go into the Object panel > Transform > Align to Transform Orientation, then move the camera on the axis to align it correctly with the plane:


I know that, but I want to do this via python.

Hi moonboots I hope you don't mind me undeleting this since this may be useful for someone that's looking for non python solution :)
